# Git pull, aceptar cambios y commitear

Tags: git, git-push

Les consulto, estoy trabajando en un repo de git, necesito actualizar con cambios remotos y a su vez tengo cambios locales.
Para poder subir debo ejecutar:

```
git pull
git add .
git commit
git push origin master
```

Si me pueden orientar sobre que comandos ejecutar.

Comment: el primer problema te va a dar al hacer **pull** pues parece que tienes cambios. Recuerda hacer pulls despues de commitear

Comment: Que tipo de entorno estas utilizando para manejar `git` ? o solo lo estas manejando por consola ?

Comment: Por consola lo manejo y la plataforma es gitlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En efecto, así debes de trabajarlo.

`git pull` Este te ayudara a bajar los cambios del repositorio remoto y a fusionarlos con tu repositorio local.

Es lo mismo que ejecutar:

`git fetch` (Bajar cambios al `origin/master`, la rama oculta) y un `git merge` (Fusionar la rama oculta origin/master con tu rama master local). Se podría decir que `git pull` es una abreviación de estos comandos.

`git add -A` Con este prepararas todos los cambios de tu repositorio local para informarle a git que los tenga en radar para posteriormente enviarlos al repositorio remoto. El parámetro `-A` indica que se añadan todos los cambios que se realizaron en el proyecto.

`git commit -m "Texto que describa los cambios"` Con este crearemos el punto o versión de código con los cambios que se añadieron anteriormente `(git add -A). Como tip, si ejecutas un`git log` podrás visualizar las versiones en el repositorio remoto y la versión que acabas de "commitear" en tu repositorio local, es mas fácil de visualizar de es manera.

`git push origin master` Finalmente añadimos o sincronizamos esos `commits` (El del repositorio local con el del repositorio remoto), es decir, enviamos los cambios locales al repositorio remoto. Como tip, ejecuta de nuevo `git log` y podrás visualizar como la se sincronizaron las versiones local y remota `(origin/master)`.

Answer (score 2):

Si no he entendido mal la questión, quieres igualar el nuevo contenido local con el remoto y viceversa.

Para "igualar" los cambios en remoto con los de local, primero nos situamos en la rama que pertoca(si solo trabajas con master, pues en master) y realizamos:

```
git pull origin master
```

Luego para añadir todos nuestros nuevos cambios al remoto:

```
git status //no es obligatorio, es para ver los archivos modificados pendientes de sincronizar

git add -A //para traquear o preparar todos los archivos modificados

git commit -m "mensaje describiendo las acciones" //crear un comit

git push origin master //para añadir los commits realizados en remoto
```

Espero te ayude